# Magento 2 - How to restrict a selected payment method?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment

How to restrict a selected payment method in Magento 2?

[image]

Event: `etc\events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="bg_customer_group_payment_filters" instance="\Bg\PaymentRestriction\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer: `Bg\PaymentRestriction\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable.php`

```
<?php

namespace Bg\PaymentRestriction\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Bg\PaymentRestriction\Helper\Data as DataHelper;

class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    private $customerSession;
    /**
     * @var \Bg\PaymentRestriction\Helper\Data
     */
    private $dataHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $groupRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        DataHelper $dataHelper
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $result          = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote           = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $this->_logger->info($method_instance->getCode());
        $activeRule = $this->dataHelper->getPaymentMethod();
        /* Enable All payment gateway  exclude Your payment Gateway*/
        if ($method_instance->getCode() == 'checkmo') {
            $result->setData('is_available', false);
        } else {
            $result->setData('is_available', true);
        }
    }
}
```

I got a value like this in frontend.

[image]

Comment: Have you get selected method in the observer file?

Comment: Any system log or exception log? Because, this code is working.

Comment: it may work for single payment method but i was r run it on for loop its  not  disable  a payment method

Comment: Can you tell how are you looping it while multiple payments

Comment: No need to use the else part as by default it will show other payment methods. You only need to set is_available false for the methods which you dont want to show.

Comment: looping mutiple payment method https://prnt.sc/pyikm0  and  result is https://prnt.sc/pyileh

Comment: The result is in the array. Right?

Comment: @divyasekar is this question solved?

Comment: yes its solved by @Dhaduk Mitesh answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<?php

namespace Bg\PaymentRestriction\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Bg\PaymentRestriction\Helper\Data as DataHelper;

class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    private $customerSession;
    /**
     * @var \Bg\PaymentRestriction\Helper\Data
     */
    private $dataHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $groupRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        DataHelper $dataHelper
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $result          = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $method_instance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();
        $quote           = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $this->_logger->info($method_instance->getCode());
        $activeRule = $this->dataHelper->getPaymentMethod();
        $disable_payment_methods = ['checkmo', 'purchaseorder', 'banktransfer']; // Get Method from your Restrictions
        /* Enable All payment gateway  exclude Your payment Gateway*/
        if (in_array($method_instance->getCode(), $disable_payment_methods)) {
            $result->setData('is_available', false);
        } else {
            $result->setData('is_available', true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do with or condition. Like this below way :

```
if ($method_instance->getCode() == 'checkmo' || $method_instance->getCode() == "purchaseorder") {
            $result->setData('is_available', false);
        }
```

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: for array, you can use in_array() function.